# Finding Directional Derivatives with gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

Find the derivative of the function at $P_0$ in the direction of $u$.$$f(x,\, y,\,z) = \tan^{-1}\left ( \frac{5x}{9y+2z} \right ),\,\,\, P_0(7,\,0,\,0),\,\,\, u = 12i - 3j+4k$$

I understand how to find directional derivatives, but I keep getting the wrong answer. I completed the partials for each and double checked my work with wolfram, and then I multiplied each by its corresponding direction, 12,-3,4. I get 0 for the partial of x portion, ${27}/{35}$ for the y portion, and $8/35$ for the z portion. Any clues where I am going wrong?

Comment: Since you know how to find it then you should have calculation issues!

Comment: Could you show me what the correct numbers would be in place of my 0 27/35 and 8/35?

Comment: @EconDude So what's your final answer?

Comment: 1 but I know it's wrong

Comment: The second component of the gradient is $\dfrac{9}{35}$, not $\dfrac{27}{35}$.

Comment: And the third component is $\dfrac{2}{35}$.

Comment: Ohh okay thanks, I must have added wrong or something silly